# Table of Contents が機能しない

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebookにTable of Contentsの機能を追加しましたが、画面のようになってしまいます。本来はContentsの右側に「t」のボタンが入るようなのですが、その通りにならず困っております。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

`jupyter notebook`の拡張機能である`Table of Contents`は、最近の修正でそのように変更されたと思われます。

歯車のボタン（ToC Settings）をクリックするとダイアログの中に`n`(number headings)と`r`(ToC cell)のボタンの機能が含まれています。ページ毎に設定できるようなったので、以前のように頻繁にクリックすることはないだろうという判断だと思います。